# Emails showing as Block/Hard Bounce but still being opened and clicked on

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, bounce-management

In Marketing Cloud, we are seeing emails sent to a particular domain receive a lot of Hard and Block bounces, but the same emails that are being blocked are still being opened and clicked on randomly (there is no pattern).  So this is a general question if anyone out there also sees similar behaviour?

It is possible to encounter a situation where a lot (over 100) people who regularly throw Hard/Block bounce messages but actually still open/click emails?  It is making bounce management very awkward.

Examples of these bounces are (with email addresses blanked out):
5.0.0 (undefined status) permanent failure for one or more recipients (x@x.com:blocked)
5.1.1  Generating server: x.com____x@exchange01.x.com__#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found

Comment: do you use CC or BCC on these emails?

Comment: Some firewalls click and open emails and if they think that its spam will answer with block or hard bounces. Maybe these 100 people share the same firewall system or firewalls that act the same way?